# How can I manually control the collapse button on my wordpress site

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have a problem. This is the site that i was building in x theme in wordpress using cornerstone. The problem is that nav menus where too many and causes a problem on screen width around 980px to somewhere around 1100px and the nav menus go below the brand logo. Is there a way to control that collapse button to trigger when it reached a certain width?

sorry for the win xp thing this is just a test pc for the site

[image: sorry for the win xp thing this is just a test pc for the site]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set widths of logo container and nav menu using percentages, for example 20% for the logo and 80% for the menu and apply a float to both elements, so browser will scale the width without breaking the nav to a new Line.